# Version control for Custom Postgres Function in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a custom postgres function in my Django app. Keeping it up to date with migrations works, but is very hard to code review / move changes from the DB to the migration, because each migration is an entire new block of SQL, like so:

```
def update_func(apps, schema_editor):
    schema_editor.execute(
        """
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
            public.function()
        .... ect
```

Does anyone have a similar situation and know a better way to version control the function?

Comment: Does Django's migration setup let you run a .sql file? Because the only sensible way to handle this is to have the function in its own file.

Comment: I'm not following. To load a new version of the function in a database you will need to do `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ...` as there is no way to apply a patch in the database. Furthermore if you change the function signature or `RETURN` values you will need to `DROP FUNCTION` first.

Comment: Correct. It's more that when you go to code review a change to the function, it requires a full update on the function (create or replace). This makes finding the particular change (lets say a 1 line change) very difficult to code review. I'm wondering if there's a better way to store updates to these functions than in migrations.

Comment: As @RichardHuxton said keep the function in its own file under version control. Then add to migration when you are done testing in it.

Answer (score 0):

I've also run up against this problem and ended up creating a small package to help deal with this: [`django-sqlfun`](https://github.com/radusuciu/django-sqlfun). Here's an example copied directly from the README:

#### Example

Define a custom function in your `models.py`:

```py
# models.py
from sqlfun import SqlFun
from django.db.models import IntegerField

class BadSum(SqlFun):
    """Almost returns the sum of two numbers."""
    
    app_label = 'test_project' # [optional] if omitted, sqlfun will atempt to auto-resolve it
    sql = """
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bad_sum(
            first integer,
            second integer
        ) RETURNS integer as $$
        SELECT first + second + 1;
        $$
        LANGUAGE sql
        stable;
    """
    output_field = IntegerField()
```

Then run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` and you should be good to go. You can use it in SQL: `SELECT bad_sum(2, 2)`, or in a Python queryset like so: `MyModel.objects.annotate(foo=BadSum(Value(2), Value(2)))`.